# How to include some Saturday/Sunday in a range B2:B10 as an exception to following formula WORKDAY(TODAY()+1, -1, Data!$A$2:$A$22)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to include some Saturday/Sunday (Saturday/Sunday is completely random like suppose B2 is having 12th Nov 2023, B3 having 25th Nov 2023 and so on) in a range B2:B10 as an exception to following formula WORKDAY(TODAY()+1, -1, Data!$A$2:$A$22).

Currently it excludes all the weekends and range A2:A22 has some holidays to exclude. I want to include some weekends as given in range B2:B10, but I'm not sure how to include some Saturday/Sundays specified in range B2:B10.

Comment: Please post some sample data showing your present and output data using **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** also I would suggest you to look into **[WORKDAY.INTL()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/workday-intl-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d)**

Comment: Have a look at Networkdays.intl()

Comment: @SolarMike Networkdays.intl() doesn't gives option to include random Saturday/Sunday. Hence couldn't include the dates included in range B2:B10. My Formula (=WORKDAY(TODAY()+1, -1, $A$2:$A$22)) is not displaying 12th November 2023 as it is present in B2. Similarly on 25th November it should display 25th as it is present on B3 and so on for B4:B10.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya WORKDAY.INTL() doesn't gives option to include random Saturday/Sunday. Hence couldn't include the dates included in range B2:B10. My Formula (=WORKDAY(TODAY()+1, -1, $A$2:$A$22)) is not displaying 12th November 2023 as it is present in B2. Similarly on 25th November it should display 25th as it is present on B3 and so on for B4:B10.

Comment: You can specify a list of holidays which you can specify as random Saturdays and Sundays...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=IF(
    OR(TODAY() = $B$2:$B$10),
    TODAY(),
    WORKDAY(TODAY() + 1, -1, $A$2:$A$22)
)
```